# Is possible to update metadata ("type" : "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)") with rest api?

Tags: update

I am able to do it when the metadata field do not receive a collection. 
In case of collection I receive the error

> {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot
>   deserialize data for type
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection."}}}',
>   cookies: [] }

Example of what I am trying to do

```
 "__metadata" : {
            "type" : "SP.Data.Global_x0020_File_x0020_LibraryItem"
    },
        "Domains_x0020__x0026__x0020_ESAs" : {
        "__metadata" : {
            "type" : "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
        },
        "results" : [
           {
                "Label" : "Family Care",
                "TermGuid" : "eb17c3ca-d402-4740-974c-0f2b31cf100b",
                "WssId" : 20
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: have a look to this post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7baa1477-9fe0-4338-8043-6ae101c9dbd4/updating-metadata-for-file-using-sharepoint-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: when I try to do it to a field that can only receive one tag I can do it... as in the example you sent me (@Supermode) without problems... the problem is that I can receive an array of them... and I always receive that error...

Answer (score 4):

According to [eirikb's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/171294), I tried to implement it and I've really faced a lot of issues.

So, I'll try to be clearer and to help futur developers to handle it correctly.

Here is what worked for me:

> How can I retrieve all taxonomy fields via REST API?

It exists a hidden list which will give you all the taxonomy fields:

**EDIT:** Sharepoint indexes this list, it means that if you add some new taxonomy fields, this list will not be up to date. **In order to force the update of this list, you will have to set all your new taxonomy fields at least once on a document set metadata of taxonomy type**. After that, you will be able to see them into that list. Also, it is paged after 100 items, you will have to use the call inside "__next" property of the body response in order to get the next 100 (& x) taxonomy fields.

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TaxonomyHiddenList')/items?$select=IdForTerm,Term

Results:
[
   {
      "IdForTerm": "19f40567-ef4c-41b0-a023-039275d66efd",
      "Term": "My test tag"
   },
   {
      "IdForTerm": "f2413c10-301d-4fe6-a171-ff4ad73bbafa",
      "Term": "Another tag for test"
   },
   ...
]
```

---

### Retrieve the hidden InternalName

> Alright, but imagine you want to set one of those taxonomy fields to a
>   metadata of a document set or a list item or whatever. How can you
>   handle it ?
>
> As simple as below, for our example, we will say that **our metadata** is named **MyTaxonomySharepointField**.
>
> I actually don't know why but you will not be able to set taxonomy values by directly using the original name of your metadata (which is **MyTaxonomySharepointField**). For that purpose, you will have to retrieve the real InternalName which is hidden behind the metadata **by suffixing it with "_0"**, ***thank you to eirikb***.
>
> **Retrieve the hidden InternalName like that:**

```
/_api/web/availableFields/getByTitle('MyTaxonomySharepointField_0')/InternalName

Giving you a result like:
{
  "d": {
          "InternalName": "p45b125f993940dca2b573bf64a02cff"
       }
}
```

Once you'll retrieve the hidden InternalName, you will have enough infos to be able to set some taxonomy values on a metadata of TaxonomyField type.

---

### Formatting values

> **A taxonomy value has to be formatted** like this (according to the received properties from the TaxonomyHiddenList call):

```
 '-1;#Term|IdForTerm;'
```

> Where if you use the first field from the TaxonomyHiddenList call, **it should be rendered like**:

```
'-1;#My test tag|19f40567-ef4c-41b0-a023-039275d66efd;'
```

> For developers who **want to set multiple values**, you should use the **'#' separator** by concatenating your formatted values (still using my first call for the example below):

```
'-1;#My test tag|19f40567-ef4c-41b0-a023-039275d66efd;#-1;#Another tag for test|f2413c10-301d-4fe6-a171-ff4ad73bbafa;'
```

---

### Final result

> Now, **here is the final datas to post for updating the metadatas** of your document set (for example):

```
{
  "Title": "My new document title",
  "Description": "Here is an updated document set via REST API",
  "p45b125f993940dca2b573bf64a02cff": "-1;#My test tag|19f40567-ef4c-41b0-a023-039275d66efd;#-1;#Another tag for test|f2413c10-301d-4fe6-a171-ff4ad73bbafa;"
}
```

NB: *p45b125f993940dca2b573bf64a02cff is the hidden field of your metadata* **MyTaxonomySharepointField**

Comment: BTW this method to update MM with SharePoint REST also works with the MSFT Graph API, by performing a patch request with the value in the format "p45b125f993940dca2b573bf64a02cff": "-1;#My test tag|19f40567-ef4c-41b0-a023-039275d66efd" cfr https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working solution by Beau Cameron: http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/update-using-rest-to-update-a-multi-value-taxonomy-field-in-sharepoint.

I can't say it's a very nice solution, but hes done some impressive work. I have tested the hack, and it works!

To sum it up must find the **InternalName** of the taxonomy field which holds the value. It has same **Title** as your taxonomy field, just with added **_0** to the title. Something like this:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Test')/Fields/GetByTitle('MyMMField_0')/InternalName
```

When you create/update your item add that internal name as a property, with a String as value, formatted`WssId;#Name|Guid;#WssId;#Name|Guid#...`. E.g.,

```
let d = {};
d[MyMMField_0InternalName] = terms.map(term => `-1#;${term.id}|${term.name};`).join('#');
```